# Example of non-Noetherian non-UFD Krull domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

After a confusing session of hopping through Wikipedia articles, I
started trying to summarize for myself some of the inclusions and
relations among the many types of integral domains. Right now I'm just
gathering and organizing facts from various sources, rather than going
through all the proofs in detail. (To be honest, my knowledge of
commutative algebra is embarrassingly poor, and I haven't even
understood all of the *definitions* yet. But one has to start
somewhere...)

Anyway, I have a few questions about things that I haven't been able
to figure out on my own, and I'll start with this one:

**Are there Krull domains that are neither Noetherian nor UFD?**

(I would guess yes, but I haven't seen any examples. The standard example
of a non-Noetherian Krull domain seems to be $\mathbf{Z}[X_1,X_2,\dots]$ with countably many variables,
but that's a UFD unless I'm mistaken.
And $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a non-UFD which is a Dedekind domain, hence a Krull domain and Noetherian.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT** $\: $ UFDs are precisely the Krull domains with trivial class group. So it suffices to exhibit a non-Noetherian Krull domain with nontrivial class group. One way to do this (and much more) is to use Claborn's techniques for constructing Krull domains with arbitrary abelian class groups - see e.g. Section 14 of Fossum's book *The Divisor Class Group of a Krull Domain*, $1973$.

I don't have Fossum's book at hand, but according to Example $49$ of Hutchins: *Examples of Commutative Rings,* he uses $\rm\:T =\: R\big[\{x_i,y_i,u_i,v_i\}_{\:i\:\in\: I}\big]/(\{x_i\:u_i-y_i\:v_i\}_{\:i\:\in\: I})\:,\:$ for $\rm\:R\:$ Krull, and for $\rm\:I \ne \emptyset\:.\:$ $\rm\:T\:$ is a Krull domain, but not a UFD (it has divisor class group $\rm\:Cl(T)\cong\! Cl(R)\oplus \mathbb Z^I)\:.\:$ $\rm\:T\:$ is non-Noetherian if $\rm\:R\:$ is, or if $\rm\:I\:$ is infinite. Hence the sought example.

Comment: Thanks! A perhaps stupid question: is $I$ the same thing as the index set $S$, or is it the ideal that you quotient out? (By the way, I ordered Hutchins's book on inter-library loan the other day, but I haven't got it yet.)

Comment: Bill, the author of the book you mention is Fossum, not Claborn.

Comment: @George Yes, of course. Thanks. Hans: Yes, typo corrected.

Answer (score 6):

What about $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}][X_1,X_2,\ldots]$? This is not a UFD and non-noetherian.

Comment: Is it obvious that it's a Krull domain?

Comment: After reading the defn of a Krull domain on Wikipedia I'd have to say no.

Comment: Actually, I believe that every polynomial extension of a Krull domain is Krull, and since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a quadratic ring of algebraic integers (and hence Dedekind, and therefore Krull), it should follow that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}][X_1,X_2,\cdots]$ is Krull.

Comment: Just for the record, let me mention a reference which confirms that $A[X_1,X_2,\dots]$ (with infinitely many variables) is a Krull ring if $A$ is, namely a Remark below Proposition 4.3 in *Lectures on Unique Factorization Domains* by P. Samuel from 1964 (available in a retyped pdf version as number 30 [here](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/index.html)).