# Example of non-Krull integrally closed BFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Here's another question in the same spirit as [my previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70434/example-of-non-noetherian-non-ufd-krull-domain):

**Are there any integrally closed BFDs which are not Krull domains?**

Some background information:

A BFD (bounded factorization domain) is defined as an atomic domain where the number of factors is bounded for each element.
(More precisely: every nonzero nonunit $x$ can be factorized into irreducibles,
but not necessarily uniquely,
and there is a number $N(x)$ such that whenever
$x=a_1 \dots a_r$ is such a factorization, then $r \le N(x)$.)

Unless I've misread something, the following relations hold (with strict inclusions):
$$
\{ \text{Noetherian domains} \}
\subset
\{ \text{BFDs} \}
\quad
\Bigl( \subset
\{ \text{ACCP domains} \}
\Bigr),
$$
$$
\{ \text{Noetherian domains} \} \cap \{ \text{integrally closed domains} \}
= \{ \text{Noetherian domains} \} \cap \{ \text{Krull domains} \},
$$
$$
\{ \text{Krull domains} \}
\subset
\{ \text{integrally closed domains} \},
$$
$$
\{ \text{Krull domains} \}
\subset
\{ \text{BFDs} \}.
$$
(Disclaimer: Trying to navigate in this jungle of classes of integral domains has got my head spinning, so I'm not 100% sure about anything at the moment...)

For the purposes of drawing a correct Venn diagram involving these relations (and many more!),
I would need to know whether there is equality or strict inclusion in the relation
$$
\{ \text{Krull domains} \}
\subseteq
\{ \text{BFDs} \} \cap \{ \text{integrally closed domains} \}.
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $D$ be a domain with quotient field $K$.
The ring of *integer valued polynomials* is defined as
$$
\operatorname{Int}(D) = \{\, f \in K[X] \mid f(D) \subset D \,\}.
$$
It is known that if $D$ is a BF-domain, then so is $\operatorname{Int}(D)$. 
If $D$ is a Dedekind domain with finite residue fields, then $\operatorname{Int}(D)$ is a Prüfer domain (in particular integrally closed), but does not satisfy the ascending chain condition on divisorial ideals. Hence it is not a Krull domain.

Thus, for instance, the rather beautiful ring $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z)$ is a non-Krull integrally closed BF-domain.

See the book *Integer Valued Polynomials* by Cahen and Chabert, in particular Chapter VI, for background on integer valued polynomials. (But note that some of the results on factorization properties are outdated.)

**An example which is moreover not Prüfer:**

This example can be adapted to obtain a ring which is (completely) integrally closed, not Krull, not Prüfer, and BF. Let me first recall how a bunch of ring-theoretic properties behave for $\operatorname{Int}(D)$.

If $\operatorname{Int}(D)$ is Prüfer, then $D$ is an *almost Dedekind domain* (all localizations at maximal, equivalently prime, ideals are discrete valuation rings) with all residue fields finite. In particular, almost Dedekind domains are $1$-dimensional Prüfer domains.

Moreover, $\operatorname{Int}(D)$ is integrally closed if and only if $D$ is. Similarly, $\operatorname{Int}(D)$ is completely integrally closed (c.i.c.) if and only if $D$ is. (For Noetherian domains, being c.i.c. and being integrally closed are equivalent. In the non-Noetherian case, being c.i.c is a stronger property.)

Recall a convenient ring-theoretic characterization of Krull domains: A domain $D$ is Krull if and only if it is completely integrally closed and a Mori domain (satisfies the ascending chain condition on divisorial ideals).

It is also known (see P.-J. Cahen, S. Gabelli, E. Houston, *Mori domains of integer-valued polynomials*, J. Pure. Appl. Algebra, 153(1), 2000) that $\operatorname{Int}(D)$ Mori implies $D$ Mori.

So, to get $\operatorname{Int}(D)$ to be BF, integrally closed, non-Prüfer, non-Krull we want that $D$ is

- BF,
- integrally closed,
- not an almost Dedekind domain (to ensure non-Prüfer),
- not c.i.c. or not Mori (to ensure non-Krull).

Actually, it would be better if $D$ is even c.i.c. but not Mori.
Here are two possibilities:

1. Take $D=K[X,XY,XY^2,XY^3,\ldots] \subset K[X,Y]$. By exercise I.3.14 in L. Fuchs, L. Salce, *Modules Over Non-Noetherian Domains*, $D$ is integrally closed but not c.i.c. It is easy to see that it is 2-dimensional and BF.
2. Incidentally, $D=\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z)$ is c.i.c., non-Krull, 2-dimensional and BF. So
   $$
   \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z))
   $$
   is non-Krull, non-Prüfer, c.i.c., BF. I haven't seen this ring before; it's rather amusing that this works! You can in fact replace $\mathbb Z$ by any Dedekind domain with finite residue fields and get the same result.

**Edit:** The following may be an easier example. If $D$ is integrally closed, non-Krull, BF then so is $D[X]$. ($D[X]$ is Krull iff $D$ is Krull.) $D[X]$ can moreover not be Prüfer ($D[X]$ is Prüfer iff $D$ is a field). So, for instance $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z)[X]$ also works. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about integer valued polynomials to see quickly whether actually $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z)[X]$ is a proper subring of $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z))$ or whether they are equal. (If a domain $D$ is an intersection of localizations at prime ideals with infinite residue fields, then $\operatorname{Int}(D)=D[X]$ is trivial.)

Comment: Great, thank you! This was a somewhat unexpected answer, since apparently (when I look back at my old Venn diagram) I had gotten the impression somewhere that a BFD which is Prüfer must automatically be Dedekind (hence Krull). But this example shows that that's wrong. So a follow-up question would be if there are any BFDs which are integrally closed but not Krull and not Prüfer either...

Comment: Exactly. In fact $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb Z)$ is a somewhat classical example of a non-Dedekind Prüfer domain. It is $2$-dimensional. (Unlike $\overline{\mathbb Z}$, the other classical example).

Comment: Wow, that was a quick update! I'll have to digest it for a while (and learn some more algebra too...), but this should be very helpful!

Comment: Sure. Btw, being a Mori domain is a sufficient property for a ring to be a BF-domain. The c.i.c. property of a Krull domain is somewhat orthogonal to that. It ensures that all nonzero divisorial fractional ideals are invertible with respect to the divisorial product; so the nonzero div. frac. ideals form a (lattice-ordered) abelian group. The Mori property then ensures that the group is free abelian. Compare Krull/c.i.c. to Dedekind/Prüfer: In a Prüfer domain the nonzero frac. ideals form a group, the ACC of the Dedekind domain ensures it's free abelian.